# BroadcastReceiver как сделать, чтобы при перезапуске не перезагружалось?

Tags: android

Наследую от класса BroadcastReceiver клаcc Notifications (Notifications extends BroadcastReceiver), в MainActivity запускаю таймер, как сделать чтобы при перезапуске приложения, таймер продолжал работать, а не перезапускался

```
private Notifications alarm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
    alarm = new Notifications();
    alarm.setAlarm(context);
```

Это в Notifications

```
 public void setAlarm(Context context) {
    Intent dopInt=new Intent(context, Notifications.class);
    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pi= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,dopInt,0);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 5220000L, pi);//5220000L
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас происходит ровно то, что вы написали. Каждый раз при вызове `onCreate` метода активити у вас заново создаётся аларм. Если вам это не нужно, значит вам нужно проверять запущен ли он уже и в этом случае ничего не делать. Проверить можно так:

```
/**
 * checks if alarm is up and should be up and update its state if need
 */
public void checkAlarm() {
    Intent intent2check = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), ReceiverTimer.class);
    intent2check.setAction("MyAction");
    boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 42, intent2check,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
    if (alarmUp) {
         //уже запущено, ничего не делаем
    } else {
         //Ничего не запущено, запускаем
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему то, данный метод не работает на телефоне, хотя на эмуляторе работает, версия одна и та же. Может быть проблема в телефоне (настройках)?

Comment: Intent intent2check = new Intent(context, Notifications.class);
        intent2check.setAction("MyAction");
        boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent2check, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
        if (alarmUp) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Приложение запущено! " + (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)-1),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            alarm = new Notifications();
            alarm.setAlarm(context);
        } //Я вот так изменил не знаю, не знаю почему на телефоне не работает(

Comment: @артемШеломенцев, попробуйте для Intent action задать такой же, каким проверяете. Т.е. если как в примере - `MyAction`